# Using Texmaker and Tex Live

Tags: texlive, texmaker

I am new to LaTex but I study chemistry and I am looking for alternatives to word, openoffice writer, libreoffice writer... MiKTex would not install on my computer and I instead installed Tex Live on my Windows 10 computer to act as a distributor for Texmaker. I am having troubles building my documents and I'm wondering if I can use these programs together? Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Which troubles?

Comment: Again welcome. Which programs are *these programs*? Win 10 and TeX Live?

Comment: Yes, you can use TeXmaker with TeX Live. If that's what you are asking.

Comment: I made a tutorial for MiKTeX and Texmaker under Windows 7 - maybe it helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FxKtwdob2RQ